# WooCommerce login form missing view password

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using `woocommerce_login_form()` to generate a WooCommerce Login form but it's missing the View Password toggle. My default login form and my registration form both have the toggle switch.

Is it possible to add this to the form that is generated with `woocommerce_login_form()`?

```
function my_render_wc_login_form( $atts ) { 
  if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {  
    if ( function_exists( 'woocommerce_login_form' ) && 
        function_exists( 'woocommerce_output_all_notices' ) ) {
      //render the WooCommerce login form   
      ob_start();
      woocommerce_output_all_notices();
      woocommerce_login_form();
      return ob_get_clean();
    } else { 
      //render the WordPress login form
      return wp_login_form( array( 'echo' => false ));
    }
  } else {
    return "Hello there! Welcome back.";
  }
}
add_shortcode( 'my_wc_login_form', 'my_render_wc_login_form' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to use jQuery to add the icon to the form and then toggle the form field type from password to text.

```
function my_render_wc_login_form( $atts ) { 
  if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {  
    if ( function_exists( 'woocommerce_login_form' ) && 
        function_exists( 'woocommerce_output_all_notices' ) ) {
      //render the WooCommerce login form   
      ob_start();
      woocommerce_output_all_notices();
      woocommerce_login_form();
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.woocommerce-form-login #password').after('<a class="show-password" href="#">' + '<?php echo __('<i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>', 'woocommerce'); ?>' + '</a>');
            $('body').on('click', 'a.show-password', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var passwordField = $('.woocommerce-form-login #password');
                var passwordFieldType = passwordField.attr('type');
                var toggleText = $(this).text();
                if (passwordFieldType == 'password') {
                    passwordField.attr('type', 'text');
                    $(this).html('<?php echo __('<i class="fa fa-eye-slash" aria-hidden="true"></i>', 'woocommerce'); ?>');
                } else {
                    passwordField.attr('type', 'password');
                    $(this).html('<?php echo __('<i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>', 'woocommerce'); ?>');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php  
      return ob_get_clean();
    } else { 
      //render the WordPress login form
      return wp_login_form( array( 'echo' => false ));
    }
  } else {
    return "Hello there! Welcome back.";
  }
}
add_shortcode( 'my_wc_login_form', 'my_render_wc_login_form' );
```